# How to keep Excel open with no files open?

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I have a single Excel file open and I close it, sometimes the app closes (quits?) as well, but sometimes the app stays open. What's driving this behavior, and how do I make it always stay open?

(This is Office 365 on Windows 11)

Comment: I have this configuration including the OS.  If I close the file (not exit) Excel stays open 100 percent of the time. Make sure both Office and Windows 11 are right up to date. Updates to both in the last 72 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't close it via Close (`X`) button on the top right corner of the application nor via File -> Quit. Those two options close files and quit the applications.

Use File -> Close to keep Excel opened.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>, which closes sub-windows rather than windows.  Note: this works with most applications with multi/tabbed windows.